# Error filling reportResource not found at: :Branch_Summary_SubReport1.jrxml

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have main report and calling two sub-report. In Jasper Studio it is working, when we deploy in server below error am getting.

ERROR : "Error filling reportResource not found at: Branch_Summary_SubReport1.jrxml."

```
<subreport overflowType="Stretch">
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="206" width="180" height="134" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f2b1f959-0351-4fa6-967a-edf545f59a33"/>
            <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Branch_Summary_SubReport1.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="361" width="180" height="269" uuid="1efdacc7-8f4f-4e2d-b1b2-3ad3bd778dc0"/>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Branch_Summary_SubReport2.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <subreport>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jrxml file is a report template file defined in an xml file format. it has .jrxml file name extension. this file (jrxml) cannot be used directly to generate the report. It has to be compiled to JasperReport file. JasperReport file is a binary format file with .jasper file name extension.

in your report calling two sub reports. but these files are jrxml files. hence call the compiled jasper files of these sub reports,

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["Branch_Summary_SubReport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>

<subreportExpression><![CDATA["Branch_Summary_SubReport2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

Note: don't forget to deploy the compiled sub reports (jasper files) into  correct path in the server

Comment: :Working like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @Neminath if the solution works, please accept this answer :-) Thanks!